# Javascript: insert in form

Tags: javascript, forms

I have a form.

I want to insert a new child input field before a button field, and the parent is the form.

When I try to get the form:

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
```

I get an HTML collection instead of a Node, so I can't use the form as a parent.

There is any solution to get the form as Node, without adding id or class (because I don't have control over html/css) ?

What if are multiple forms on the page instead of just one ?

Comment: So read the first item from the collection? So you click the button and it adds a field to the current form? So you can use that button to determine the form.

Comment: You'll have to loop through all form elements and find something within them that make your target form unique (i.e: an input field name).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So assuming they click the button, you can use that to reference the form.

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(this.form);
});
```

```html
<form>
  <button>FOO</button>
</form>
```

And as I stated in the comments if you have one form than you can just reference the first index

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form')[0];
```

or you can use querySelector which returns the first instance

```
var form = document.querySelector('form');
```

Comment: Just a use case, what if there is no form associated with the first button in the document.

Answer (score 1):

```
var forms = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
var firstForm = forms[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The way you are getting the form, it will return the array of form elements. If there is only one form, you must have it at 0 index of returned array. write one more line in code to get your form from the array.

```
var form = document.getElementsByTagName('form');
form = form[0];
```